# Can't use cursor select in cmd or atom

Tags: windows-10, text-editors, cursor

I am running Windows 10. When I run any of the three programs:

1. cmd
2. windows terminal
3. **PowerShell**
4. atom

I am not able to cursor select text (i.e. highlight the text with the cursor).

I have tried starting atom in safe mode, but that doesn't resolve it. I am able to cursor select text in other applications such as:

1. web browser
2. Microsoft word
3. **PowerShell ISE**

So I know this is an issue with the cursor selection and not any one application. I have tried going into Windows 10 Settings > Mouse > Additional Mouse Options > Turn On/Off ClickLock. This didn't help though.

The only solution I have now to resolve this is to restart the PC.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** run DISM and SFC:

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

That is the first step before a Windows 10 Repair Install

**Second:**  Make a new, test Windows User Profile. Log into the new User Profile and test Commands and the Cursor.

If a new User works, you need to back up the documents and email in the current User Profile and make a new User Profile.

**Third:** If the above steps do not work, run a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.